# Input element inside anchor element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="cars" action="file.php" method="post">
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('cars').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="ford" name="model" />Ford</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('cars').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="toyota" name="model" />Toyota</a>
</form>
```

However, the `$_POST['model']` gave error "Undefined index: model". What's wrong with that?

Comment: Looks invalid, why would anyone put form inputs inside anchors. I'm guessing the browser moves the elements when it's trying to fix your mistake.

Comment: Also, if you want to use the same name for both inputs in PHP, do `model[]`

Comment: What libs or framework are you using on the back-end?
Seems like a problem with your model

Comment: Why not use a `dropdown` or `radio` instead of `hidden input` inside `a`?

Comment: I put the input element inside anchor because I want the form to be submitted whenever the car name is clicked. I can't put the onclick event inside input element.

Comment: @samurai, all car names must be displayed horizontally on the top menu. Can't use dropdown nor radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to have one `hidden input` outside your `a` elements. It will get its value based on the element clicked just before `submit()`. So your form will look like this:

```
<form id="cars" action="file.php" method="post">
    <a href="#" onclick="submitModel('ford')">Ford</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="submitModel('toyota')">Toyota</a>
    <input id="hiddenModel" type="hidden" name="model" value="ford" />
</form>
```

And your javascript:

```
function submitModel(mdl) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenModel').value = mdl;
    document.getElementById('cars').submit();
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/94uxdpte/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I've solved it using jQuery already and remove the anchor tags. Well, hopefully this can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your method will work as you desire. You need to rethink your approach to this. Why not just use links and querystrings?

Here is the simplest method I could come up trying to use your techniques as I supposed there is reason for you needing to do it this way:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['model']))
    echo $_POST['model'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postBack(o) {
        document.getElementsByName('model')[0].setAttribute("value", o);
        document.getElementById('cars').submit();
    }
</script>

<form id="cars" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="model" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="postBack('ford')">Ford</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="postBack('toyota')">Toyota</a>
</form>
```